# using window function sql inside pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like the example data below.  I’m trying to create a new column in my data using PySpark that would be the category of the first event for a customer based on the timestamp.  Like the example output data below.

I have an example below of what I think would accomplish it using a window function in sql.

I’m pretty new to PySpark.  I understand you can run sql inside of PySpark.  I’m wondering if I have the code correct below to run the sql window function in PySpark.  That is I’m wondering if I can just paste the sql code inside of spark.sql, as I have below.

Input:

```
eventid customerid category timestamp
1       3          a        1/1/12
2       3          b        2/3/14
4       2          c        4/1/12
```

Output:

```
eventid customerid category timestamp first_event
1       3          a        1/1/12    a
2       3          b        2/3/14    a
4       2          c        4/1/12    c
```

window function example:

```
select eventid, customerid, category, timestamp 
FIRST_VALUE(catgegory) over(partition by customerid order by timestamp) first_event
from table



# implementing window function example with pyspark

PySpark:
# Note: assume df is dataframe with structure of table above
# (df is table)

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(“Operations”).getOrCreate()

# Register the DataFrame as a SQL temporary view

df.createOrReplaceView(“Table”)

sql_results = spark.sql(“select eventid, customerid, category, timestamp 
                FIRST_VALUE(catgegory) over(partition by customerid order by                timestamp) first_event
                from table”)

# display results
sql_results.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function in pyspark as well

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+-------+----------+--------+---------+
|eventid|customerid|category|timestamp|
+-------+----------+--------+---------+
|      1|         3|       a|   1/1/12|
|      2|         3|       b|   2/3/14|
|      4|         2|       c|   4/1/12|
+-------+----------+--------+---------+

>>> window = Window.partitionBy('customerid')
>>> df = df.withColumn('first_event', F.first('category').over(window))
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+-------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+                             
|eventid|customerid|category|timestamp|first_event|
+-------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+
|      1|         3|       a|   1/1/12|          a|
|      2|         3|       b|   2/3/14|          a|
|      4|         2|       c|   4/1/12|          c|
+-------+----------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: @AliYesili Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  So am I correct that I can just put the sql into PySpark, example: sql_results = spark.sql(“select eventid, customerid, category, timestamp 
                FIRST_VALUE(catgegory) over(partition by customerid order by                timestamp) first_event
                from table”) .  Also in your example how does the over function know to order by the timestamp field to get the first category based on timestamp?

Comment: yes you can use sql something like you used. Due to it is first value order by is not necessary but if you want you can change it like Window.partitionBy('customerid').orderBy('timestamp')